# Call a pointer-to-function outside the structure

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

I have a structure, inside it a pointer to function from the same structure. And now I need to call a pointer to function outside the structure. I give an example of the code below:

```
#include <iostream>

struct test {
    void (test::*tp)(); // I need to call this pointer-to-function
    void t() {
        std::cout << "test\n";
    }
    void init() {
        tp = &test::t;
    }
    void print() {
        (this->*tp)();
    }
};
void (test::*tp)();

int main() {
    test t;
    t.init();
    t.print();
    (t.*tp)(); // segfault, I need to call it
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void (test::*tp)();` - why do you have that outside the class. Remove it and fix your call syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(t.*tp)();` is trying to invoke the member function pointer `tp` which is defined at global namespace as `void (test::*tp)();`, note that it's initialized as null pointer in fact (via [zero initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization)<sup>1</sup>), invoking it leads to [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), anything is possible.

If you want to invoke the data member `tp` of `t` (i.e., `t.tp`) on the object `t`, you should change it to

```
(t.*(t.tp))();
     ^
     |
     ---- object on which the member function pointed by tp is called
```

If you do want to invoke the global `tp`, you should initialize it appropriately, such as

```
void (test::*tp)() = &test::t;
```

then you can

```
(t.*tp)(); // invoke global tp on the object t
```

---

<sup>1</sup> About zero initialization

> Zero initialization is performed in the following situations:
>
> 1) For every named variable with static or thread-local storage duration `that is not subject to constant initialization (since C++14)`, before any other initialization.

Answer (score 0):

@songyuanyao's answer is valid. However, are you sure you want to use your structure that way? Why not just use inheritance and virtual methods? :

```
class base_test {
public:
    virtual void t() { std::cout << "test\n"; }
    void print() { t(); }
};
```

and then you can subclass it:

```
class my_test : base_test {
public:
    virtual void t() { std::cout << "my test\n"; }
};
```

In your `main()` function (or wherever) you could have functions returning pointers or references to the base class, which are actually instances of subclasses. And this way, you don't have to worry about pointers.

The downside is that you have to know about your different tests at compile time (and then not even at the site of use, as I just explained). If you do, I'd go with the common idiom.